# There was a problemm sending the command to the program Delphi-7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I got a new laptop the other day (for gaming, school). I installed Delphi-7, only to run into errors and non-sense.

When I open a .dpr file from Windows, I get an error saying `There was a problem sending the command to the program`.

I am running Windows 8SL, I have also set the compatibility to Windows XP Service Pack 2, and its running as admin.

I've searched on Google about these errors and I keep finding stuff for Microsoft Word, Excel etc..

Is there any other options other than going back to Win7?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about this, but try running Delphi as admin. Depending on where you open your DPR file from, you may get wierd and wonderfull errors.

Comment: You don't want to run your IDE as admin. If you do that then you'll never find any standard user bugs in your program. Delphi 7 works fine on Windows 8. No need to use Windows 7.

Comment: @Kell It was on a CD our IT teacher gave us for reference, I can't open the .Dpr out of the file. I even copied it onto my main drive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So if a program doesn't work, I mustn't run it as admin?? My life is a lie! :p.. But, with or without running Delphi7.exe as admin, I still keep getting this error. I never got it on my old laptop, desktop. Strange and no wonder our IT teacher doesn't like Delphi xD (BTW not offending delphi in any way, Delphi is cool);

Comment: That error relates to the shell file association, and DDE. I'd lose the compat mode and running as admin. The big question is where you installed, and how you tackled UAC.

Comment: Are you double-clicking the file in windows or opening the project in delphi?

Comment: IIRC, Delphi 7 came out in 2002! I will never understand how one can expect it to run smoothly under an OS released ten years later. I suggest getting a recent Delphi version to avoid such problems. If it has to be Delphi 7, make sure to grant write access to the installation folder under Program Files.

Comment: @Kell Opening the project via delphi works okay, but opening the DPR file in windows causes the error.

Comment: @UweRaabe They gave us Delphi-7 for school. I would get xe2 if I had the money

Comment: Er, what did you change?

Comment: Please write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it by turning off Compatibility mode and NOT running as admin

Comment: In other words, you ran it the way you should run *anything*. Both those things are options you should try only *after* determining that something *doesn't* work. They should never be things you do by default.

Comment: I also think there's an issue with the `C:\Program Files` folder in Win7+, and it's advisable to install to a folder directly on the drive root.

Comment: Or do what I do and install to %programfiles% and add a permissive acl

Answer (score 1):

This problem ("There is a problem sending the command to the program") that seems to plague us a all occurs ONLY with Microsoft (administrator) accounts.  In my experience it does not occur if the account is a local account.

The problem is one of accounts and updates. It occurs because some Microsoft update has caused it, perhaps corrupting the Microsoft accounts themselves, but not registries or Excel-Options-Advanced-General-Ignore......dde files.  I subscribe to a technical company (its name will not be mentioned).  They worked 2 1/2 days on my machine and couldn't solve the problem. There was no recourse but to uninstall and reinstall both Windows 8 and Microsoft Office 13.  I backed up my data files adequately but forgot this would delete my e mail account and its contacts.  I also lost a few applications programs that I had purchased.  Be careful!

The point of all this is that Microsoft sent me down over 100 updates that I no longer had after reinstallation.  I didn't install them immediately, then Microsoft went ahead and installed them w/o my permission and said they would restart my computer in two days to finish installation.  Even after that there were 17 additional updates that came down and were not yet installed.  I decided to install each one of these separately (talk about time consuming) and test if my Microsoft account would open Excel without error after they were installed.  The dreaded error didn't occur in the first 100 updates or in the first 3 or 4 of the remaining 17.  Then Microsoft either took over and installed the remaining 8 updates w/o my permission OR I forgot to uncheck the remaining 8 and do them one at a time.e

Sure enough, after the remaining 8 were installed the problem was back in the Microsoft administrator account but not in the local account.  I was sickd. So I began to uninstall the 17 updates that had been installed all in one go on that date and test them in Excel and Word separately but ONE UPDATE AT A TIME!.  I got lucky.  The first one I uninstalled solved the problem.  The Microsoft administrative account now would open Excel files wihtout error.

I'm convinced the problem is one of accounts and updates caused by some update that corrupts Microsoft administrate accounts or otherwise affects the Microsoft accounts adversely.  The update I deleted was titled "Update for Windows 8 for x64-based Systems (KB2769165)".  It fixed the problem.  My Microsoft administrative account now opens Excel workbooks and Word documents without the dreaded error.

Some update is doing this to Microsoft (administrative) accounts but not local accounts themselves.  If you dare, delete some of your most recent updates one at a time and test them against Excel or Word to see if you still get the error.  You can get the updates back if you want them by having Microsoft Updates search for updates you don't have. Anyway that is my experience.  The problem is one of accounts and updates that significantly disable Microsoft accounts but not local ones.  I don't know which update will affect you because there are still so many platforms out there being used.